# How do I rotate an object around an arbitrary pivot?

Tags: fabricjs

I want to implement physical draggable behavior - when an object is dragged by a certain point the whole object "follows" that point - sort like the balls here: http://www.mrdoob.com/projects/chromeexperiments/ball-pool/

Now in order to do that, I need to set the touch-point (when the user clicks the object in order to drag it) as the rotation center. 
I havn't found a relevant property in fabric.js objects to achieve that, I tried using groups as pivots but I failed miserably. Would appreciate a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to set arbitrary origin of transformation (whether it's rotation or scaling) at the moment. But we might add support for this in the future.

Comment: @kangax I wonder if it has been changed since your last comment